# How to differanitate data from json when the data is in two dictionaries?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am fetching data from JSON. It gives response in two dictionaries. How to differentiate that dictionaries and paste the data in table view. I am using segment control in table view. One is for receiver and other is for sender.

```
 NSUserDefaults *uidSave = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSMutableDictionary *get = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    [get setObject:[uidSave valueForKey:@"uid"]forKey:@"uid"];
    NSLog(@"Dictionary Data which is to be get %@",get);
    NSData* jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:get options:kNilOptions error:nil];
    NSString *jsonInputString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSString *post = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"r=%@",jsonInputString];

    NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",caseInfoUrl]];

    NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[postData length]];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData timeoutInterval:120.0];
    [request setURL:url];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setHTTPBody:postData];

    NSError *error;
    NSURLResponse *response;
    NSData *responseData=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
    if (responseData != nil)
    {
        jsonArray = (NSMutableDictionary *)[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:kNilOptions error:&error];
        NSLog(@"Values =======%@",jsonArray);

        sender = [jsonArray objectForKey:@"sender"];
        NSLog(@"Sender^^^^%@",sender);

        receiver = [jsonArray objectForKey:@"reciever"];
        NSLog(@"Reciever$$$$%@",receiver);

    }



    if (error)
    {
        NSLog(@"error %@",error.description);
        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Server not responding" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"cancel" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alertView show];
    }


    // Set up names array
    sendArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];



    // Loop through our json Array
    for (int i = 0 ; i <sender.count; i++)
    {


        //create object
              NSString *dateTime = [[sender objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"datetime"];
        NSString *proNumber = [[jsonArray objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"pro_number"];
        NSString *statuses  = [[jsonArray objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"status"];

    [sendArray addObject:[[DataObjects alloc]initWithDate1:dateTime andCaseName1:proNumber andStatus1:statuses]];



    }

    [sendList reloadData];

}
```

Comment: Well, you look at the format in which the data is provided, and then you write code for it - that code should be pretty obvious.

Comment: And onyone using "reciever" in a public API should be flogged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a BOOL variable

```
BOOL senderSectionIsSelected;
```

If you want to load sender's data initially then in ViewDidLoad:-

```
senderSectionIsSelected=YES;
```

If you want to load receiver's data then set it to NO;

```
senderSectionIsSelected=NO;
```

Modify this

```
if (responseData != nil)
{
    jsonArray = (NSMutableDictionary *)[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:kNilOptions error:&error];
    NSLog(@"Values =======%@",jsonArray);

    sender = [jsonArray objectForKey:@"sender"];
    NSLog(@"Sender^^^^%@",sender);

    receiver = [jsonArray objectForKey:@"reciever"];
    NSLog(@"Reciever$$$$%@",receiver);

    [yourTableView reloadData];
}
```

In your numberOfRow and cellForRow load data accordingly:-

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

   if (senderSectionIsSelected)
   { 
       return sender.count;
   }
   else
   { 
       return receiver.count;
   }
}
```

In cellForRow show data accordingly:-

```
if (senderSectionIsSelected)
   { 
       yourDataTimeLabel.text=[[sender objectAtInder:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"datetime"];
       yourProNumberLabel.text=[[sender objectAtInder:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"pro_number"];
       yourStatusLabel.text=[[sender objectAtInder:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"status"];
   }
   else
   { 
       yourDataTimeLabel.text=[[receiver objectAtInder:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"datetime"];
       yourProNumberLabel.text=[[receiver objectAtInder:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"pro_number"];
       yourStatusLabel.text=[[receiver objectAtInder:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"status"];
   }
```

Now in your segmentController's action methods:-

If its segment for sender then:-

```
senderSectionIsSelected=YES;
```

If its segment for receiver then:-

```
senderSectionIsSelected=NO;
//don't forget to reload tableView
senderSectionIsSelected=YES;
```